# NASM YASM Adding numbers of an array

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm, yasm

Given the following data segment, write code in main which adds all the numbers in a. If the final sum is positive, it should be saved in RBX register, and if it is negative, then it should be saved in RCX register.

Hello! I am a bit confused on how to go about adding these, as they are all in the same segment, a.

```
segment .data
a         dd      12, 15, 17

           segment .text
           global main
main:
```

Comment: `a` is not a segment, it is a variable (holding an array of doublewords). Anyway NASM does not have the concept of variables beyond "symbols", that is, addresses. So you address the first array entry as `dword [a]` and the second as `dword [a + 4]`. Or with registers holding the values of address `a` or `4`.

Comment: @ecm Thank you! Could you please explain where the 4 comes in?

Comment: Memory on an x86-based system is byte-addressable. However, your array defined with `dd` (define doubleword) takes up one doubleword per entry. An x86 doubleword consists of 32 bits, that is, 4 bytes. So to address the second entry of the array you want to add 4 to the address of the first entry. Similarly add 4 again (or add 8 in total) to address the third entry.

Comment: You also may want to configure the assembler with a `default rel` directive, which needs to be put before the memory accesses, once. Refer to https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.2.1

Comment: @ecm: Fun fact: `default rel` seems to affect the whole file, even if specified *after* the instructions.  IDK if that's a bug or intended; seems weird to me.